# Hack for removing the last weight from a 7ft barbell?

Tags: time

Usually when I am finished doing dead lifts and I am removing the weights I have trouble with the last 45lb plate. For reference it looks like the picture below.
[image]

I find it difficult to remove the plate because the bar is uneven and both the bar and plate have the same weight. I have tried a few methods: lifting the empty end of the barbell and pulling it away from the plate (usually results in the barbell gripping the rubber plate and I look foolish). Also I have tried holding the barbell stationary with one hand and pulling off the plate with the other (usually takes several tries to work the plate off as it grips the barbell and only moves a few inches at a time). I know there has got to be a pro tip for getting that last plate off, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I found an [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub32EQNkEt0) that demonstrates an easy method for loading and unloading a barbell. Similar to BrettFromLA's answer by lifting the unloaded side straight up the weights on the loaded sided simply slide of and are stacked nicely on the ground.

Step 1: Grab unloaded side of barbell with both hands and lift upwards.
[image]

Step 2: Continue lifting the bar until it is in a vertical position.
[image]

Step 3: Once bar is positioned vertically, stand atop the loaded side and pull the bar upwards.
[image]

Step 4: Once barbell is released from weights replace it on the rack and rerack the plates.
[image]

Comment: Could you please describe the vital steps from the video, so that this answer is self contained? The video is good, but it would be even better that this answer stands on it own.

Comment: Much better, I also liked the tip in the video regarding using a smaller weight to hold the innermost weight of the ground whilst unloading the other weights as kind of a step 0

Comment: Why does this answer look like the question?

Comment: @KalleMP When I first asked the question there was just a picture of a full barbell and I said 'it looks like the barbell below but empty on one side'. After I found the video I added a screenshot to give a better example of what the barbell looked like.

Comment: @ChrisR is there any reason you haven't accepted this answer? Are there some aspects of it you don't like? To me it seems like a very good fit to your question as it stands today?

Comment: Just forgot, thanks for the reminder @holroy

Answer (score 1):

You could set the whole thing next to a bench, then lift one end up over the bench.

[image]

Pull off the weight that's above the bench.  The bar shouldn't fly up into the air because of the other weight falling to the floor, but be careful the first few times just in case.  Then pull the bar out of the weight that's on the floor.